# Spinner Button without radio button

Tags: android, themes, spinner

How to remove Radio button from spinner BUTTON, using only Themes.xml? I can remove it after applying an other style, but I can't to remove this radio button from Themes.xml by default.

```
<style name="My.Theme.Spinner" parent="android:Widget.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_bg</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerMode">dialog</item>
    <item name="android:checkedButton">@null</item>
    <item name="android:checkable">false</item>
</style>
```

Theme

```
    <style name="My.Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
        <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/My.Theme.Spinner</item>
    </style>
```

ORIGINAL adapter (with radio buttons in items)

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_item,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.registrationIds));
```

Updated Adapter (without radio):

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.registrationIds));
```

Note: Spinner items should have a radio buttons. Spinner button should be without radio.

Fragment.xml

```
<Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/small_content_padding"/>
```

See my issue: [image: Issue]

Comment: you cannot customize the spinner.Instead you can create the Context menu for button click. thanks dude...

Comment: through adapter you can do it.

Comment: After changing the adapter (adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);) - my spinner items don't have radio buttons, but spinner button - with radio button still.

Comment: can you show me your code once..?

Comment: see original post with updates

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add viewResourceid in createresource only i.e., as follows..

if you are creating with resource array.

```
adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(ActivityName.this,Your values resource id here,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); 
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

if you are creating with string[] Objects then it'll be as follows..

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ActivityName.this,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, String[]namehere);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: Good. It works for button. But my spinner dialog currently without the radio buttons. I want button without radio, but spinner items should have the radio button. It possible?

Comment: check modified answer.with the above you can get spinner without radio button, at the same time in spinner dialog you'll get radio buttons for items.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
```

instead of

```
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```