# Creating spinner like in actionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, spinner

**I want to create spinner like `actionBar's spinner` dropdown view**

[image]

I have reffered to the following questions :

1. [How to make spinner like actionbar in native android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685011/how-to-make-spinner-like-actionbar-in-native-android)
2. [ICS spinner outside ActionBar and not working dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212823/ics-spinner-outside-actionbar-and-not-working-dropdown-menu)

But no luck in finding the solution.Whenever I use spinner in my activity :

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spiner_id);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.day, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And in xml :

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spiner_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

It gives output :

[image]

I want the spinner in dropdown view instead of the current dialog form.

P.S : Working on 4.2+ version

@Pankaj Kumar Thnak you for quick reply.I have added `android:spinnerMode="dropdown"` to my spinner view in xml and it works fine.But the dropdown list contains `RadioButtons` also.How can i get it removed from the list?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Have you made any change in your `/res/values/style.xml`? If you made one, try to undo it and see the change.

Comment: No, I've never changed anything in my style.xml .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `android:spinnerMode="dropdown"` to Spinner.

Like

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spiner_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

---

*And more details about removing radio buttons, read [Spinner Button without radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123647/spinner-button-without-radio-button).*

Comment: Thank you it worked for the dropdown spinner.I have edited my question with the output m getting now.I also want to remove the radioButtons .How to do that ?

Comment: @Manishika Look into the link which I have added into answer. That is for removing radio buttons.